# Redirect all non-root routes to index.html on Amazon Linux 2 and Apache

Tags: apache-httpd, webserver, amazon-ec2, apache-virtualhost, virtual-host

An Amazon Linux 2 instance is using Apache to host an Angular 7 app.  The Angular 7 app includes not just `index.html`, but also several `.js` files and a subdirectory named `assets`.

> **What specific syntax do I need to use in order to ensure that requests to Apache for all non-specified routes get redirected to the `index.html` located in the `DocumentRoot`?**  Note that the required syntax needs to also allow all the `.js` files and the contents of the `assets` directory to be served as secondary requests when the client browsers are loading `index.html`.

For example, if a remote web browser requests `mydomain.com/randomCharacters`, I want Apache to return `index.html` the same way that Apache would respond to a request to `mydomain.com` with `index.html`.  And then `index.html` must be able to get access to the `.js` files and the contents of the `assets` subdirectory.

(In this case, `DocumentRoot` is a directory entitled `/var/www/mydomain.com/public_html`.  Also, the `/var/www/mydomain.com/public_html` directory includes 1. `index.html`, 2. several `.js` files, and 3. an `assets` subdirectory containing things like images, etc.)

I would like to use `RedirectMatch` inside of a `VirtualHost` block to keep the configuration as clean as possible.  Here is what I have in mind.  How does the following need to be modified?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain.com/public_html
    ErrorLog /var/www/mydomain.com/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/mydomain.com/requests.log combined
    RedirectMatch 302 ^/(?!index.html$).+ http://mydomain.com  
</VirtualHost>
```

---

**Forensic Analysis of Results:**

---

When try the above with the Network Tab in the Developer Tools of Firefox open and I make a request to `http://mydomain.com` while the `RedirectMatch 302 ^/(?!index.html$).+ http://mydomain.com` is in the `VirtualHost`, the result is that all requests to `/` are shown to have given a `304` response, while all requests to named files like scripts and stylesheets are shown to have given `302` responses.

Also, when I view the `html` page source for the same request, I see that the contents of `index.html` were indeed served correctly, but that the browser remained empty because the code in `index.html` was not able to access the `.js` files or the contents of the `assets` subdirectory.

> So the problem is that `RedirectMatch 302 ^/(?!index.html$).+ http://mydomain.com` needs to be re-written to allow for the `.js` files and for the contents of the `assets` subdirectory.  **What specific syntax is required to resolve this so that Apache can successfully server up the Angular 7 app no matter what character string is added after http://mydomain.com?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `RewriteRule` like this in a `VirtualHost` context:

```
RewriteEngine On
# if not a regular file
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
# and not a directory
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
# then rewrite to index.html
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.html [L]
```

I you want to keep your config "as clean as possible", then don't do stuff like this and let Apache return a HTTP 404 as it should.

Comment: Please have a look at the edit I just made to the OP.

Comment: OK.  Your approach works.  But why do you think that I should allow Apache to return a 404 here?  The result of your code is that now the Angular 7 app running in the browser is able to return its own 404 page for every route after mydomain.com that is not defined in the Angular app.  This allows separation of concerns, so that the Angular app can manage all the routes not specified on the server.  What is wrong with this?

Comment: Your `RedirectMatch` simply doesn't catch all the paths you want. You could modify it and add lots of exceptions for every file you add somewhere to your `DocumentRoot`. But I don't think this is a good idea. The solution above rewrites all URI paths to `/index.html` which are not found in your `DocumentRoot`. If your app only needs files inside the `DocumentRoot` and has no other rewriting or proxying, then this could work for you.

Comment: I said if you want your config "as clean as possible"... What's wrong with a "page not found" if the page is not found? Sorry, I have no idea how your Angular app works.

Comment: For one thing, the approach desired in the OP and given in your answer isolates all the views in the browser app, so that the server can focus on serving a complete app instead of having the server try to be a UI app in addition to simply being a server.  Thank you and +1 for answering the question in the OP.